# (CSS) Grid Box layout with dynamic sizing images

Tags: html, css, tile, box

I'm trying to create a tile layout / grid box layout with dynamic sizing images. The Idea is to create this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2T4L.jpg

But the size of the box needs to change depending on the width or height of the browser. Even better would be when the boxes also get less per row if the browser is too short in width. A full row of boxes/images should always be the full width of the page. And each image is square.

Someone created this 
http://codepen.io/davidkpiano/pen/EaxjBj

With SASS, but I have no clue how to work with SASS but thought it could be achieved without SASS.

This is what I was playing around with but I never got It really working

```
.img_left {
        float: left;
        padding-bottom: 500px;

}

.img_left img {
       width: 19.82vw;
       height: 19.82vw;
}

.img_work img {
        width: 19.82vw;
        height: 19.82vw;
        float: left;
 }
```

.img_left is my div for the very first picture.
Is there a good solution to my problem?

Comment: You can click the eye icon in codepen to toggle the compiled view: http://i.imgur.com/XQek16y.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The codepen script you posted is realy simple. Let me "decode" Sass for you, it might be what you looking for:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.tile {
    float:left;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 25% 0 0 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
}
.tile > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
// Make sure rows are flush
.tile:nth-child(4n + 1) {
    clear: left;
}

// Small screens
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .tile {
        width: 50%;
        padding: 50% 0 0 0;
    }
        .tile:nth-child(2n + 1) {
        clear: left;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So why is sass used so commonly? Is it that much of an improvement of coding? Or does it actually bring in new features. I have no idea.

Comment: @user3648229 I'm not the OP of this answer, but I'd like to throw in my opinion on that.  Using SASS/LESS has completely changed and improved CSS development for me.  It both makes development a lot faster and adds functionality like variables and functions.  I can't imagine web development without it at this point.

Comment: Actually, is your choise if you want to use SASS or not. SASS has much more features that meets the eye. Nesting rules is one of them.
Make sure to check [Compass](http://compass-style.org) a CSS Authoring Framework. You will get some info there. If my answer was good for you, dont forget to accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good SASS to CSS converter for you to use in the future. At least until you become more familar with SASS.

http://sassmeister.com/